# Locale nl_NL missing in docker BitBucket pipeline

Tags: docker, docker-compose, bitbucket, gettext, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm using this `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file to test my application before deploying it on the servers. We're missing the nl_NL locale after installing the dependencies. We're using the following file:

bitbucket-pipelines.yml:

```
image: php:7.2.6

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: PHPUnit
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip git zlib1g-dev libicu-dev g++ locales
          - locale-gen && locale-gen nl_NL
          - echo "nl_NL UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen && echo "en_EN UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen && echo "enUS UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen && echo "en_GB UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen
          - locale -a
```

The locale -a output after installation is as following:

```
locale -a
<1s
+ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
```

I did expect the nl_NL locale in this command. This will result in failing tests. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the order of your commands. First, add `nl_NL UTF-8` (and anything else you need) to `/etc/locale.gen` and only then run `locale-gen`.

Comment: Thanks... So easy :)